# Como faço para extrair o nome de várias pastas dentro de um diretorio?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Preciso entrar dentro de uma pasta chamada */users*, onde dentro dela a diversas pasta e copiar o nome de todas as pastas, segue o exemplo.

[image: Este é o caminho que até as pastas]

Eu queria poder pegar o nome dessas pastas e salvar em uma lista no python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função **[`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)**. Esta função irá retornar todos os arquivos e todos os diretórios dentro no diretório especificado.

Para checar se o item é um diretório, você pode usar a função [**`isdir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir). Note que esta função precisa receber como parâmetro o caminho **completo** do item a ser checado e que o retorno de `listdir` são caminhos **relativos**, então deve-se usar a função `join` para concatenar o nome do diretório base com o nome do item a ser checado.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join

base_dir = '/users'

diretorios = [a for a in listdir(base_dir) if isdir(join(base_dir, a))]
```